# Tooltip Not Displaying in IE9 for Embeded Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I have a very simple Visualforce page that I have added to a Case layout.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" >
    <a href="#" title="tooltip title" >hover here</a>
</apex:page>
```

The tooltip displays fine in all browsers except IE9. I've attempted changing the doctype to html-5, adding a pageblock, pageblocksections, all without any luck.

The tooltip does display properly when viewing this as a standalone Visualforce page (not embedded in the case page layout.)

Going completely custom with the Visualforce page is not an option. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen a similar behaviour - not specific to tooltips. In my case I got strange rendering of some components on a page rendered in an IFRAME on a VF-page. The VF you display on the Case layout will be displayed through a IFRAME so I expect this could be the same problem.

If you use the Developer tools you will notice that the site has been forced IE into Compat mode - this claims to be because salesforce.com/force.com exists on a Microsoft owned list of sites that needs to be / has asked MS to force compat mode on them.

By adding a X-header you can force IE into a specific mode. If you put this line in the constructor of your controller - if you only use standard controllers you can build a simple extension controller that does this for you. It should be placed in the constructor and no other methods of the controller since the header needs to be set before anything is sent to the browser.

```
Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=edge');
```

This will force the visiting IE browser to always be on the latest mode.